# Portable VPN client with split tunneling support

Tags: portable, vpn

I'm looking for a VPN solution so that I can access my home LAN from my office's PC. My router is capable of being a VPN server.

But I don't want all connections to go to this VPN tunnel. I want only a few apps, like FireFox, Dropbox, Evernote, etc.

And to make things more complicated, I don't wanna install this VPN client nor use Windows'. It's safer if it's portable. Maybe if it opens a HTTPS or SOCKS proxy, and I configure apps to connect to it.

Any ideas of any program that might do it?

Comment: I assume it should be for Windows? What's your price margin if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: As far as I remember VPN client needs to install network driver, so it cannot be portable.

Comment: If it solves my need and isn't extremelly expensive, I can buy it. Better know it exists and not buy than not even know it exists.

Comment: Indeed I think the way to go would be some software that connects to a VPN server and provides HTTPS and SOCKS proxy, so that then any app could be configured to connect to it.